# POSTGRESQL Foreign Key Referencing Primary Keys of two Different Tables

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables Books and Audiobooks, both of which have ISBN as their primary keys. I have a table `writtenby` that has an `isbn` attribute that has a foreign key constraint to Books and Audiobooks ISBN.

The issue that comes up when I insert into `writtenby` is that postgresql wants the ISBN I insert into `writtenby` to be in both Books and Audiobooks.

It makes sense to me to have a table `writtenby` that stores authors and the books/audiobooks they have written, however this does not translate to a table in postgresql.

The alternative solution I am thinking of implementing was having two new relations `audiobook_writtenby` and `books_writtenby` but I am not sure that is a good alternative.

Could you give me an idea of how I would implement my original idea of having a single table `writtenby` referencing two different tables or how I could better design my database? Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 90):

There's more than one way to do this in PostgreSQL. Personally, I prefer this way.

```
-- This table should contain all the columns common to both 
-- audio books and printed books.
create table books (
  isbn char(13) primary key,
  title varchar(100) not null,
  book_type char(1) not null default 'p'
    check(book_type in ('a', 'p')),
  -- This unique constraint lets the tables books_printed and books_audio 
  -- target the isbn *and* the type in a foreign key constraint.
  -- This prevents you from having an audio book in this table 
  -- linked to a printed book in another table.
  unique (isbn, book_type)
);

-- Columns unique to printed books.
create table books_printed (
  isbn char(13) primary key references books (isbn),
  -- Allows only one value. This plus the FK constraint below guarantee
  -- that this row will relate to a printed book row, not an audio book
  -- row, in the table books. The table "books_audio" is similar.
  book_type char(1) default 'p'
    check (book_type = 'p'),
  foreign key (isbn, book_type) references books (isbn, book_type),
  other_columns_for_printed_books char(1) default '?'
);

-- Columns unique to audio books.
create table books_audio (
  isbn char(13) primary key references books (isbn),
  book_type char(1) default 'a'
    check (book_type = 'a'),
  foreign key (isbn, book_type) references books (isbn, book_type),
  other_columns_for_audio_books char(1) default '?'
);

-- Authors are common to both audio and printed books, so the isbn here
-- references the table of books.
create table book_authors (
  isbn char(13) not null references books (isbn),
  author_id integer not null references authors (author_id), -- not shown
  primary key (isbn, author_id)
);
```

Comment: You da real mvp, any limitations known to this method?

Comment: @Weier: *Generic foreign keys* is neither a relational concept nor a SQL concept. In any case, the foreign keys in the schema I posted are not generic foreign keys in the sense the article defines that term.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' You're right. I read your code too fast and thought you were proposing the same concept as implemented in those "Generic FK".

Comment: How do you delete a book entry? Would you have to to run two queries, where the first one deletes a record from `books_printed` and then the second one deletes it from `books` ?  It would be more "natural" to just delete a record from `books` and rely on a cascade mechanism, but it won't work here

Comment: @BVtp: "ON DELETE CASCADE" is fundamental database design knowledge. Use of it in most SQL database design questions isn't called for, because its use is too application-specific. Ditto for updatable views, table and view permissions, etc. The structure I posted supports adding 'ON DELETE CASCADE': for example *...foreign key (isbn, book_type) references books (isbn, book_type) on delete cascade...*

Comment: strange, but I've tried adding the `on delete cascade` and when I delete a record from `books`, it shows me an error saying : `update or delete on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "books_printed_isbn_fkey" on table "books_printed". Detail: Key (isbn)=(1    ) is still referenced from table "books_printed"`.

However, the solution seems very interesting if the deletion I mentioned can be worked out. The one thing that's a bit "inconvenient" here is that you would necessarily need to run a query just to look through the "printed books" for example, instead of just opening the table

Comment: edit ^: the cascade does work actually, I just had to add the `on delete cascade` to the PK line also.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create enum type for `book_type` from the example?

Comment: @hazer_hazer: Enums aren't in the SQL standards. As such, their usage, features, and behavior varies from one dbms to another. I work with several dbms. For me, enums in the database are more trouble than they're worth. Enums in application code are a different story.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', I don't get it. Why we need pg if we cannot use its power due to difference with SQL standard. All dbms differ and thus we use the one we prefer more. My question was like "Is it a good idea to use enums as record type"

Comment: @hazer_hazer: "Use the good features of a language; avoid the bad ones." (*The Elements of Programming Style*, 2nd ed., Kernighan and Plauger, p19) IMO, enums in PostgreSQL are a bad one. In addition to the reasons I gave above (and there are several more), you can argue that they don't fit into the relational model, which requires that all database data be represented in columns of rows in tables. Having said that, *you* can do anything you want with respect to PostgreSQL. But you can't persuade me that enums are a good idea here.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Please explain the merits of having the primary key of `books_printed` (and `books_audio`) `references book(isbn)` when additionally you have a foreign key constraint on `(isbn, book_type)`. Is this necessary and if so, why?

Answer (score 8):

You could use table inheritance to kinda get the best of both worlds.  Create the audiobook_writtenby and books_writtenby with an `INHERITS` clause referencing the writtenby table.  The foreign keys could be defined at the child level as you describe, but you could still reference data at the higher level.  (You could also do this with a view, but it sounds like inheritance might be cleaner in this case.)

See the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-inheritance.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html

Note that you will probably want to add a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the writtenby table if you do this.

Answer (score 5):

RDBMS's do not support polymorphic foreign key constraints. What you want to do is reasonable, but not something accommodated well by the relational model and one of the real problems of object relational impedance mismatch when making ORM systems. [Nice discussion on this on Ward's WIki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForeignKeysCanOnlyReferenceOneTable)

One approach to your problem might be to make a separate table, known_isbns, and set up constraints and/or triggers on Books and AudioBooks so that table contains all the valid isbns of both type specific book tables. Then your FK constraint on writtenby will check against known_isbns.

Comment: The relational model and SQL databases actually handle this kind of thing well. The problem isn't relational or SQL; the problem is that one of the obvious constraints is implemented incorrectly.  (The constraint is that the ISBNs for books and for audiobooks are drawn from the same domain.)

Answer (score -3):

In this specific example there is absolutely no need to use multiple tables. Just use the table "Book" and add the columns from "AudioBook", if applicable. If you have to differentiate on table level with very specific columns, create views. Have you checked to see if a "Book" and an "Audio Book" with the same content have the same ISBN?

Comment: Even though your answer is technically correct I don't think it should be followed. PostgreSQL supports modelling this cleanly quite well. Folding together multiple objects into a single table usually ends up in a big mess.

Comment: some of the issues with this approach are: sparse table(in a row lots of empty columns), maintainability(it's confusing to look at a table and see columns that aren't related to all rows), performance(related to sparse tables)