# Organizing Tables with Inherited Structure but no new Attributes

Tags: database, postgresql, inheritance, many-to-many

I don't have a ton of experience with databases/postgres, and I've been struggling for the past couple of days to figure out the best way to organize the following

- I have three different tables which have the same attribute (only the one).

  - Let's call them A1, A2, and A3, since that's how I drew them in my ERD
- These three tables share the same three relationships with 4 outside tables
- These three tables have unique relationships between themselves, specific to which table you're considering

The link to my ERD attempts is in a comment below.

**Attempt 1**

I had decided on this structure, but I realized that the joiner tables 1, 2, 3, and 4 would have to have a column structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE joiner (
  1_id integer REFERENCES 1 (id),
  A1_id integer REFERENCES A1 (id),
  A2_id integer REFERENCES A2 (id),
  A3_id integer REFERENCES A3 (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (1_id, A1_id, A2_id, A3_id)
);
```

This feels incorrect though, because only one of A1_id, A2_id, A3_id will be populated at a time (XOR).

**Attempt 2**

I then considered "inheritance", the way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068033/postgresql-foreign-key-referencing-primary-keys-of-two-different-tables) does it. But the problem is that all of these classes: A, A1, A2, and A3 all have just one attribute. Like

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  attribute integer
);

CREATE TABLE A1 (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  attribute integer
);

etc
```

So if I have A123 inherit from A, they literally won't have any attributes. They would only be separate tables to help delineate the relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  attribute integer
);

CREATE TABLE A1 (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES A (id) NOT NULL,
);
```

Also, if I want to get all the A1 tuples related to a particular tuple in table 1, I'd probably still have to have extra columns in A to indicate which sub-table to search, which is the same problem as in Attempt 1:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  A1_id integer REFERENCES A1 (id),
  A2_id integer REFERENCES A2 (id),
  A3_id integer REFERENCES A3 (id),
  attribute integer
);
```

**Attempt 3**

I had initially considered and rejected this structure. This is the cleanest in terms of smallest database structure, but it necessitates if/else queries, which I've been told are messy and point to bad database design.

I have the table A which has the single attribute (not shown in the ERD), and then a type attribute, which tells you which of A1, A2, or A3 the table is. The if/else queries come from traversing the A12 and A23 relationships. If the tuple is of type A1, I'm going to want to grab back all related A2 tuples.

**Attempt 4**

This is the last and perhaps most ridiculous idea I came up with. I thought I'd include it though, to show that I at least considered it.

There are 14 joiner tables to join 7 tables with actual content. But with this setup, we don't have any empty columns.

**Final Thoughts**

I feel like the best options are Attempts 1 and 4, since Attempt 3 deals with cases and Attempt 2 just makes a set of extra joiner tables basically (and isn't an improvement over 1).

They all have drawbacks though, and I haven't been able to find anything advisory about database design that goes past basics, so I thought I'd check to see which would most follow standards.

Thanks guys!

**EDIT:**

The more I think about it, the more Attempt 4 seems the right thing to do. Sure there are a million joiner tables, but there's no confusion about what exactly you're getting when you query one of them.

I also briefly considered (just now) having a sequence for the primary keys of A1, A2, and A3 but according to "https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50652/sharing-a-single-primary-key-sequence-across-a-database", that's needless and almost a bad idea.

Comment: Here's the link to my attempts to organize my ERD properly: http://imgur.com/a/F3Jji

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with Attempt 4, cause my queries will be simpler and easier to write.

I also want to be able to start on any of the tables included and be able to get all related information cleanly. Since I include so many more joiner tables, all I have to do is walk the relationship, there's no extra checking involved.