# Can I have a foreign key refers to primary key of two different table?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Background information: the client is a company provides both home repair service and hotel room booking service.

Here are the tables I wrote base on the requirement paper:

```
RoomBookingService{
Service_ID(PK)
Cost
Start_Date
End_Date
Room_ID
}

HomeRepairmentService{
Service_ID(PK)
Repair_Type
Staff_ID
date_Of_Repair
}

Invoice{
Invoice_ID(PK)
Service_ID(FK) REFERENCES both HomeRepairmentService.Service_ID and RoomBookingService.service_ID
Customer_ID
}

Payment{
Payment_ID(PK)
Invoice_ID
Payment_method
}
```

If I am wrong, what will be the solution to make it right?

Also, I am wondering whether I would need separate payment and invoice table for these two different services because these two services contain unique attributes on their own.

Comment: you can't make foreign key reference to two tables, however you can add foreign key in `RoomBookingService` and `HomeRepairmentService` and refer to `Inovice` table. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/10068033/3953479

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to have a `Service` table with just one column, `Service_ID`. `RoomBookingService`, `HomeRepairmentService` and `Invoice` should all have `Service_ID` as Foreign key, referencinf `Service.Service_ID` table.

Comment: So you mean I can use Service.Service_ID as the primary key of both RoomBookingService and HomeRepairmentService? So what will be the SQL query if I want to insert a row into, for example, RoomBookingService?

Comment: You'd have to insert it into both the tables `Service` and `RoomBookingService` in a transaction