# Two one-to-many relationships, where the "many"-table is the same

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have two data classes that I need to store in a PostgreSQL database. One is request and one is a response.
The requests consists of some meta-data and a bunch of orders. The response consists of some other meta-data and the same bunch of orders, but with a few extra fields. The relationship in the OO code looks roughly like this

[image]

and a (reduced) data representation of the tables could look like this

[image]

I would like to create a common `Order`-table since 14/16 fields are the same and the rest are just None. I would then create a table `Request` and a table `Response`, and keep a foreign key constraint between and `Order` and either a `Request` or a `Response`. However, this would mean that my `Order` table need two columns, where only one is populated.

Is this the "canonical way" (if such a way even exists) to maintain such reference to a common child table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POSTGRESQL Foreign Key Referencing Primary Keys of two Different Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068033/postgresql-foreign-key-referencing-primary-keys-of-two-different-tables)

Comment: You are showing a Java/C# entity diagram and then asking for a table design.  Can you instead show us sample data in tabular form, as it would appear in SQL?

Comment: @vicpermir Not exactly. The difference is that I want my `Order`-table to have a one-to-many relationship to both the Request and the Response. The field in the `Order`-table can always be the same, so no need for this kind of "inheritance".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the comment. The thing is, I am not sure how to structure it in SQL, hence this question. The reason the diagram is how I receive the data in an OO scheme, and now I need to store this in an SQL database somehow.

Comment: I would suggest that you figure out what the raw data looks like in a table at least.  I didn't answer, because I felt I would have to guess at the very data.